# Symfony2 Controller for Uri is not callable but the Uri is ok, what's happening?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller

I've just found this problem in other users, but the solution is not working for me, because apparently my code is right:

I have this route:

```
rs_shoppingcart:
    pattern:  /carrito
    defaults: { _controller: rsBundle:Default:shoppingcart}
```

And this is the Controller:

```
    public function shoppingcartAction(){ ...
               ...
               if($peticion->getMethod() == 'POST'){

               ...
```

And basically, it's a form, first time I can go to the "carrito" route, but when I submit the form, It give me the next error:

> The controller for URI "/carrito" is not callable.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem occurs in this line:

```
defaults: { _controller: rsBundle:Default:shoppingcart}
```

in `reBundle` a namespace is missing - you should add ther the parent directory of your bundle. In example - `GeneralRsBundle:Default:shoppingcart`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `shoppingcart` matches the string (not ignoring case) before `Action` in your `Controller` method.